# Yandex Cloud Api Gateway Websocket Ошибка при отправке сообщения

Tags: javascript, websocket, yandex-cloud

Я пытаюсь подключить свой проект на VueJS 3 с помощью websocket в Yandex Cloud Api Gateway. Вот инструкция https://cloud .yandex.com/en-ru/docs/api-gateway/tutorials/api-gw-websocket

В примере показан способ подключения через wscat. Все работает. Но при подключении через браузер происходит следующее: Соединение нормальное, но при отправке сообщения оно выдает ошибку

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://d5dao5nnb9dr9t11nt2b.apigw.yandexcloud.net/connections' failed: Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8.`

**Не могли бы вы подскажите мне, как нормально реализовать подключение к Yandex Cloud Api Gateway через websocket?**

**API GATEWAY CODE**

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Test API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /connections:
    x-yc-apigateway-websocket-message:
      summary: Get connection identifier
      operationId: getConnectionID
      parameters:
        - name: X-Yc-Apigateway-Websocket-Connection-Id
          in: header
          description: Websocket connection identifier
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Connection identifier
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
      x-yc-apigateway-integration:
        type: dummy
        http_code: 200
        http_headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
        content:
          text/plain: '{"connection_id":"{X-Yc-Apigateway-Websocket-Connection-Id}"}'
```

**JS CONNECTION CODE**

```
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://d5dao5nnb9dr9t11nt2b.apigw.yandexcloud.net/connections");
socket.onopen = function() {
  console.log("[open] Connection established");
  socket.send('TestMessage');
};
```

**Console Result**

```
[open] Connection established
Sending to server
WebSocket connection to 'wss://d5dao5nnb9dr9t11nt2b.apigw.yandexcloud.net/connections' failed: Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8.
```

Answer (score 0):

Недавно столкнулся с подобной проблемой, но со стороны сервера, который должен обрабатывать/отвечать на запросы клиентов, при помощи метода [send](https://cloud%20.yandex.com/en-ru/docs/api-gateway/tutorials/api-gw-websocket).
В результате общения с поддержкой подсказали закодировать текст в base64. Это помогло.
Документацию обещали поправить.

Попробуйте, возможно, это поможет.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Мне в поддержке ответили так же. Но я пробую всячески кодировать... и Base64 и UTF8  Результат такой же.  Не пойму в какой части проблема? Со стороны клиента или со стороны сервера?